# python-docx returning empty .docx file?

Tags: python, docx

So I'm trying to redirect my print output into a docx file which I'm using the python-docx module for. However, when I run my script it creates the file but when I try to open this file it returns a blank document.

The code I've written is here:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document

page = requests.get('https://www.digitalmarketplace.service.gov.uk/digital-outcomes-and-specialists/opportunities?q=&statusOpenClosed=open')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

def list_open_tenders(soup):
  opps = soup.find_all('li',{'class':'app-search-result'})
  print(f"No. Opportunities:   {len(opps)}")
  for result in soup.find_all("li", attrs={"class": "app-search-result"}):
    print(50 * '*')
    print(f"Title:       {result.h2.a.text}")
    print(f"Description: {(result.p.text.strip())[0:150]}...")
    print(f"Link:        {result.h2.a['href']}")
    document = Document()
    paragraph = document.add_paragraph(list_open_tenders(soup))
    document.save('wordy.docx')

list_open_tenders(soup)
```

If I run that it will output my print just fine in the console and it creates the wordy.docx file, it's just it misses the key part which is to write that output to wordy.docx. Does anyone why this might be and if there's a workaround?

Comment: You're creating a document, adding an empty paragraph, and saving for each element in the loop. https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html

Comment: So you are adding an empty paragraph here while creating a new document in a loop and saving it with the same name?

Comment: Create and save the document outside of the loop, and add paragraphs with string variables you want to write.

Comment: hmm I'll see what I can do thanks